# raphael-min.js:10 Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M,0,0"

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, linechart, morris.js

I have trouble plotting a line graph in morris js. Below is my javascript code for retrieving data from the datebase and keep encountering this error in my console log "raphael-min.js:10 Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "M,0,0"."

```
    <script>
var balance = '<?php $connection = Yii::$app->getDb();$command = 
  $connection->createCommand("select count(*) as tally from 
 tbmessages_external where  field3='310000' and
 (datex>=TO_DATE(to_char('21-02-18 15:00:00'), 'dd-mm-yy hh24:mi:ss')  
   and datex<=TO_DATE(to_char('21-02-18 17:59:59'), 'dd-mm-yy 
   hh24:mi:ss'))");
    serialize($command);?>';


console.log(balance);
var line = new Morris.Line({
    element: 'bi-chart',
    resize: true,
    data: [
        { hours: '00:00', a: balance},
        { hours: '01:00', a: balance},
        { hours: '02:00', a: balance},
        { hours: '03:00', a: balance},
        { hours: '04:00', a: balance},
        { hours: '05:00', a: balance},
        { hours: '06:00', a: balance},
        { hours: '07:00', a: balance},
        { hours: '08:00', a: balance},
        { hours: '09:00', a: balance},
        { hours: '10:00', a: balance},
        { hours: '11:00', a: balance},
        { hours: '12:00', a: balance},
        { hours: '13:00', a: balance},
        { hours: '14:00', a: balance},
        { hours: '15:00', a: balance},
        { hours: '16:00', a: balance},
        { hours: '17:00', a: balance},
        { hours: '18:00', a: balance},
        { hours: '19:00', a: balance},
        { hours: '20:00', a: balance},
        { hours: '21:00', a: balance},
        { hours: '22:00', a: balance},
        { hours: '23:00', a: balance},
    ],
    //data:balance,
    xkey: 'hours',
    ykeys: ['a'],
    labels: ['BI'],
    lineColors: ['#3c8dbc'],
    hideHover: 'auto',
    parseTime: false

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In you php code you just prepare a sql command but don't execute  you should add ->queryScalar(); 
for retrive the Count(*) data  (scalar is fo first column of first row)

```
<script>
  var balance = <?php  $connection = Yii::$app->getDb();
      $command = $connection->createCommand(
            "select count(*) as tally 
            from tbmessages_external 
            where  field3='310000' 
            and (datex >= TO_DATE(to_char('21-02-18 15:00:00'), 'dd-mm-yy hh24:mi:ss')  
                    and datex<=TO_DATE(to_char('21-02-18 17:59:59'),
                           'dd-mm-yy hh24:mi:ss'))")->queryScalar();;
   echo $command . ';' ;

   ?>';
```